# Do we have a taxonomy other than part of speech?

Tags: english, corpora, parts-of-speech

I'm trying to create an educational system, and I would like to have more taxonomies than a simple part of speech. For example, I would like to be able to categorize words into:

1. Tree => object
2. Kindness => attitude
3. Keyboard => computer part
4. Car => transportation, object

A better example can be found at this [English word groups](http://www.world-english.org/wordgroups.htm) page.

Do we have such classification in any corpus of English language? Is it related to linguistics at all, to categorize words by other taxonomies too.

Comment: I think you are looking for ***ontology***, not taxonomy. And, yes, there are several.

Comment: It's very limiting to stick to categorizing single words.  For linguistic analysis, we need phrases.  We have always needed them -- read over Aristotle's **Categories**, where he considers what expressions can answer a given question.

Comment: @parsh, ontology means studying existence of things. How that can be used as the notion of classification and categorization?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. You could be interested in subset relations between things referred to by any linguistic expression; or you could be specifically interested in conceptual relations expressed by lexical expressions (words). In the latter case, you would be looking at e.g. "reindeer" and "mammal" or "herbivore", but not "white reindeer" (but: some languages have a lexical item for "white reindeer"). BTW ontology relates to classification because a classification is of things that exist.

Comment: No, you're talking about ontology in philosophy. I'm talking about ontology in linguistics and computer science. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ontology_(information_science). See http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/databases-and-information-systems/research/yago-naga/yago/, for example.

Comment: A couple of ontologies produced as samples for my undergraduate semantic classes: [_Verbs of Cutting_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf), and _Verbs of Unaided Bodily Motion_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/words/). The textbooks for that class included Frawley's _Linguistic Semantics_. A guide to that book is [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/frawleyq.pdf), and an outline of the topics covered in the chapter on "Entities" (i.e, nouny words) is [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/meta4/FrawleyEntities.pdf). Both of these are interesting taxonomies themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked whether there is a corpus with such a classification, I'm going to give you an example of a semantic tagger. The [UCREL Semantic Analysis System (USAS)](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/usas/) can be run on a corpus just like a parts of speech tagger and relies on a taxonomy of 21 general levels of classification:

[image]

Below that there are up to four sub-divisions, here is the classification for *time* expressions:

[image]

There is a free web-service where you can [try out](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/wmatrix) the semantic tagger.

Here is an example of the sentence "My dog loves biting the postman." It's a bit cryptic, but that's because it's supposed to be machine-readable.

```
My_Z8 dog_L2mfn loves_E2+ biting_B1 the_Z5 postman_Q1.2/I3.2/S2.2m ._PUNC
```

Comment: that's very interesting. It's getting close to what I have in mind. Does it have help on reading the result and understanding it?

Comment: Yes, you need to look up the codes in the [classification tree](http://ucrel.lancs.ac.uk/usas/Lancaster_visual/Frames_Lancaster.htm). For exampe, 'loves_E2+' is something to do with "emotion" since it's in category E.

Answer (score 0):

Another kind of resource of interest is a wordnet: It shows several relations between words like synonym, hyperonym, hyponym. The prototypical wordnet is the Princeton wordnet available from http://wordnet.princeton.edu/ .